# Auto increment the alphanumeric characters Id

Tags: php

I want to auto increment the alphanumeric character's ID and i want to savi it in to my database.

For example:

```
Example-001
Example-002
Example-003
Example-004
Example-005
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP doesn't specify their DBMS and hasn't shown minimal effort in attempting to solve their problem.

Comment: What are you using it with ?

Comment: On php with mysql server bro

Comment: Autoincrement => do you want to do this in a database? If so: don't do it. If you just need the format with leading zeroes, a `sprintf('Example-%03d',$int);` would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to store it like that -- bad idea.

Instead, just have your `ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT` in your MySQL and do something like

`<?php echo "$dbRow['name']."-".$dbRow['id'];`

Or, if you're OCD -

```
while(strlen($dbRow['id'] < 3) {
     $dbRow['id'] = "0".$dbRow['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to increment the number at the end of those strings, and you have to do it in PHP, try this:

```
$str1 = "Example-001";
$parts = explode("-",$str1);
echo sprintf($parts[0] . '-%03d', $parts[1]+1); // Example-002
```

However I would guess there's a better way, possibly at the database level to accomplish what you need. You would need to explain more and post more code.

Example: http://3v4l.org/V2R5m

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: when i am saving it in database its giving error

Comment: error is :  Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: @user3133377 Well you haven't shown any database code in your question, so we have no clue what you're doing there. You can see from my Example link that the PHP code works. Sounds like you have a different issue somewhere else now, and need to post more code for us to see.

Comment: @user3133377 The code I posted does not do array to string conversion. There is some issue with how you are implementing this. Would have to see more of your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but since you tagged this as `PHP` and you're asking how "to auto increment an alphanumeric character's ID," here's a solution:

```php
for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
    $number = str_pad($i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo "Example-$number <br />";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Example-000  
Example-001  
Example-002  
Example-003  
Example-004
Etc...
```

Not only is does it increment the number, but it does it *automatically-ish*.